# position primefaces dialog at the center of the screen

Tags: css, user-interface, dialog, datatable, primefaces

There are quite a few dialogs in different pages, and to position them at the center of the screen, I wanted to apply one css. This however didn't work.

```
   .ui-dialog{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -100px;
  }
```

On adding .ui-dialog-content, ui-dialog-titlebar to the css, some parts of the dialog showed in the top left corner, some at the center, and some overlapped. How do I make the dialog box pop up at the center of the screen.
Thanks

Comment: On the showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf every pop-up dialog appears centered on Google Chrome (22.0.1229.94).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should not use CSS to center primefaces dialogs. by default, they are centered. so I suggest that you remove any custom css to center dialogs, and if still dialogs are not centered submit an issue to primefaces.

Comment: Or use attribute `position` with `center` as value

Comment: I found that my app had a jquery UI theme generated in 2010 which was now causing it to center offscreen (while scrolled down)

Comment: how do you fix it ?